# Finding the selected option of one dropdown among many with same class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

the html is

```
<select class='pay-type' style='width:100%'>
  <option>Credit Card</option>
  <option>Cash</option>
  <option>Credit Note</option>
  option>Gift Voucher</option>
  <option>Cheque</option>
</select>
```

i reproduce this select by inserting the same html onto new div's. i have a module written which triggers when selection changes in the dropdown. How do i get the selected value of the exact dropdown in the onclick function? the following code doesnt seem to work.

```
$('.pay-type').change(function(){
  console.log($(this).filter('option :selected'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `.text()`

```
$('.pay-type').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).filter('option :selected').text()); // to show the text
    console.log($(this).val()); // to show the value
});
```

Note: There are a few things off in your code.

1. The options do not have a value. Though not strictly essential, it is good practice to have them. If you want to store values in a database, you will now have to store using the `text` method only.
2. If you keep your first `option` as *Select a payment method*, the user can also select the *Credit card* option to show in the selected div. Now to do the same thing, the user will have to select something else first and then go back and select that option to see it

Comment: That doesnt seem to work. I tried $(this).filter('option :selected').val();   but that didnt work either.

Comment: That's not how you use `.val()`. See my updated answer. Also, there is a missing `<` in your html. I hope it is a typo here and not in your actual code

Comment: [Works indeed](http://jsfiddle.net/BKLt5/). @Spinbad please note that without `value` attribute to the options, the drop down list is pretty much useless as you won't know what the user selected when submitting the form.

Comment: i added a value attribute to all the options. It was a mistake on my part to have tried to access the val() without specifying the value for the options. Thanks guys.